# Double loop to populate subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dict of dataframes that I want to use to populate subplots.
Each dict has two columns of data for x and y axis, and two categorical columns for hue.

Pseudo code:

```
for df in dict of dataframes:
    for cat in categories:
        plot(x=col_0, y=col_1, hue=cat)
```

**Data for example:**

```
dict_dfs = dict()
for i in range(5):
    dict_dfs['df_{}'.format(i)] = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':np.random.randn(10), # first column with data = x axis
                                                'col_2':np.random.randn(10), # second column with data = y axis
                                                'cat_0': ('Home '*5 + 'Car '*5).split(), # first category = hue of plots on the left
                                                'cat_1': ('kitchen '*3 + 'Bedroom '*2 + 'Care '*5).split() # second category = hue of plots on the right
                                               })
```

**IN:**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(dict_dfs.keys()), 2, figsize=(15,10*len(dict_dfs.keys())))
for i, (name, df) in enumerate(dict_dfs.items()):
    for j, cat in enumerate(['cat_0', 'cat_1']):
        sns.scatterplot(
            x="col_1", y="col_2", hue=cat, data=df, ax=axes[i,j], alpha=0.6)

        axes[i,j].set_title('df: {}, cat: {}'.format(name, cat), fontsize = 25, pad = 35, fontweight = 'bold')
        axes[i,j].set_xlabel('col_1', fontsize = 26, fontweight = 'bold')
        axes[i,j].set_ylabel('col_2', fontsize = 26, fontweight = 'bold')
        plt.show()
```

**OUT:**

the 10 subplots are created correctly (5 dfs * 2 categories), but only the first one (axes[0, 0]) gets populated. I am used to create subplots with one loop, but it's the first time I use two. I have checked the code without finding the issue. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Does it change if you move the last line (`plt.show()`) out of the loops (i.e., un-indent it to the beginning of the line)?

Comment: it does ! thanks a lot, can you submit it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plt.show()` is within the scope of the `for`-loops, so the figure plot gets shown after the initialization of the first subplot. If you move it out of the loops (un-indent it to the beginning of the line), the plot should correctly be shown with all subplots.